# Chloropleth map using python won't show

Tags: python, plotly, figure

I am a new user to Python. I am attempting to create a US county level chloropleth map. To get started I've been reading tutorials on how to do this [here](https://plotly.com/python/choropleth-maps/) . The problem is when I execute the code exactly as it is written in the tutorial, I can't actually see the finished figure. A figure-object is created, but no plot. At the end of the day I am really looking to take this example and apply it to my own data.

Here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
with urlopen('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/geojson-counties-fips.json') as response:
    counties = json.load(response)

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/fips-unemp-16.csv", dtype={"fips": str})

import plotly.express as px
fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(df, geojson=counties, locations='fips', color='unemp',
                           color_continuous_scale="Viridis",
                           range_color=(0, 12),
                           mapbox_style="carto-positron",
                           zoom=3, center = {"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
                           opacity=0.5,
                           labels={'unemp':'unemployment rate'})

fig.update_layout(margin={"r":0,"t":0,"l":0,"b":0})
fig.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are running your code from a standalone script, you can set the default renderer for `plotly` by adding the following lines at the beginning of your script:

```py
import plotly.io as pio
pio.renderers.default = "browser"
```

In this case, your default browser will be used as a renderer. Other renders are available (take a look [here](https://plotly.com/python/renderers/)).

Moreover, if you are running your code in a jupyter notebook, it is enough to have `fig` as last command of the cell and the figure will be displayed.

Comment: That actually does appear to show the figure - which is amazing. I have been using Spyder for my code as its most similar to what I'm used to. 

But I'm generally curious now as to how to get it to render and display within Spyder.

Comment: Try with `pio.renderers.default='svg'`

Comment: When I use that I display a ValueError: 
The orca executable is required to export figures as static images,
but it could not be found on the system path.

Comment: You have to install [orca](https://plotly.com/python/orca-management/#configuring-the-executable)